# CSS Button color only change word's background color no whole button when hover

Tags: css

I want make the button when hover change the background color but my css button  only change the word's background color, not the whole button color when hover. Is something wrong in my css?

snippet added

```css
.popup1_btn {
    width: 210px;
    height: 45px;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background-color: #d3db2c;
    color: black;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 30px auto 0;
    line-height: 45px;
    font-family:"Avant Garde Demi BT";}
 

    .popup1_btn :hover{
         background-color: black;
         color: #d3db2c;}
```

```html
<div class="popup1_btn"><a href="http://example.com/">I'm Interested</a></div>
```

image link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5XoU.png

Comment: Then just use background-color property on hover css event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems the space before the `:hover` in your CSS caused this problem.

After changing `popup1_btn :hover` to `popup1_btn:hover`, it works.

Here's a working snippet im which the entire button paints black on hover:

```css
.popup1_btn {
    width: 210px;
    height: 45px;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background-color: #d3db2c;
    color: black;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 30px auto 0;
    line-height: 45px;
    font-family:"Avant Garde Demi BT";}


.popup1_btn:hover{
    background-color: black;
    color: #d3db2c;
 }
```

```html
<div class="popup1_btn"><a href="http://example.com/">I'm Interested</a></div>
```

Comment: @XuezhengLow If my answered helped, voting up and accepting my answer as correct would be appreciated.

Comment: @XuezhengLow Why should it change? You put the same color code on the hover too: `#d3db2c`...

Comment: when no hover is black, when hover is #d3db2c, but it only change the background color not the word color